# How to use the results of an included php file as a query parameter

Tags: php, mysql

My apologies if this question is dumb/the answer is very simple, I am new to programming.

I want to use my PHP file "parseurl.php" to first get a number at the end of the page URL, and then use that number in another php file as a parameter in a SQL query. I got parseurl.php to echo the number as needed, and I can call that number in another php file with the include function. What I cannot get it to do, is successfully use the number from pageurl.php to query my database.

Here is my code so far. It works as it is shown here without the parseurl.php included (with a "0" as the image_id criteria), but what I want is for the image_id= the result from parseurl.php. I have tried various syntax combinations to put the result from parseurl.php in that spot, but they haven't worked...

```
<?php

include("connection.php");
include("parseurl.php");

connection();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE image_id = 0;";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['image'];
$db->close();

?>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: what code have parseUrl.php?

Comment: `<?php
function getLastPathSegment($url) {
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); // to get the path from a whole URL
    $pathTrimmed = trim($path, '/'); // normalise with no leading or trailing slash
    $pathTokens = explode('e', $pathTrimmed); // get segments delimited by a slash

    if (substr($path, -1) !== '/') {
        array_pop($pathTokens);
    }
    return end($pathTokens); // get the last segment
}

    echo getLastPathSegment($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>`

Comment: That was adapted from another solution someone posted on stackoverflow... basically the number for the image ID always comes after the last "e" in the url

Comment: and can you post your full url how to indentify the image id ?

Comment: it would be like this: mysite.com/database/image243/ (it would return 243 in that case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include literally includes php code onto the page. If you want the script to return something you will have to do a curl call or something similar and assign the returned value to a variable.
Reference this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

In order to get your code working rewrite the code at parseurl.php to return php that has a variable you will be using in the script above.

For example set `$parsedID = "Whatever";` **inside parseurl.php**. and then use $parsedID in the query like so `$sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE image_id = " . $parsedID;`

The way you are trying to do the above is having the script return something and to use that returned value inside of your main script. This can be done using curl. First you need to make sure the CURL library is installed: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Then use this code in place of the include statement:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
curl_exec("parsedURL.php", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$parsedID = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I was able to do what you suggested above where I set $parsedID = the result within the parseurl.php file, and if I just have a php file that includes the parseurl.php file, and then echo $parsedID, it works (returns the number). But for some reason if I try the next step above (using $parsedID in place of the 0 in my code for the image_ID), it won't work... but again I'm new to this and may be doing it wrong...

Comment: Can you var_dump() the row object? Could be the query is returning nothing, the row is mislabeled or something else we could have missed. Have you also tried executing your sql directly onto the database with the imageid?

Comment: This worked! I made an error in the syntax at first which is why it didn't work the first time. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

i think so you don't need parse your url if you know what you want
you can change parseUrl.php with this code:

// url
// domain.tld?image=1

```
if(isset($_GET['image']) {
   // do sql query as SELECT * FROM table WHERE image = $_GET['image']
}
```

but you should prevent $_GET for attackers or sql inject like htmlspecialchars...

or check if image is number like a if(is_numeric($var)) ....